# Using a python library (Biopython) from a python program on a different folder that is installed

Tags: python-3.x, path, python-import, libraries, biopython

I generally like to make my python programs in a text editor and then run them after they are complete instead of line arguments. Thus, I save those .py files on a convenient folder location instead of Python program files.

I then run my .py file using Command Prompt. However it has not worked for the Biopython library as **import Bio** gives back a **Traceback No module named 'Bio'**. However, using line arguments directly on python shows it is installed.

I have never had this issue with Python in general and other downloaded libraries (**import numpy** for example works fine). How do I make the files available to be open from any location?? Or how do I provide the path in import?

To clarify and add: 
1) I use Python from Windows 10
2) I downloaded and installed Python(3.7) from python.com
3) I downloaded Biopython using pip (and all other libraries I downloaded)
4) I also tried it on Jupyter notebook and also does not work to import Bio, whereas Import numpy does.

Thanks!

Comment: What OS do you use? (Windows / Mac / Linux) How did you install Python? (python.org / Anaconda / Homebrew) How did you install Biopython? (Conda / pip / downloaded source)

Comment: 1) Windows 10  / 2) Python (3.7) was downloaded and installed from python.com but now I have Anaconda too / 3) I used pip to install biopython, directly from windows command prompt (not on Python line argument) / 4) I also tried import Bio using Jupyter notebooks and it does not work either (import numpy does for comparison)

Comment: Use Anaconda. Use the Anaconda prompt. Use conda to install Biopython. Also, take note that the programs you use (like Jupyter notebook) run from a different Python installation than you installed Biopython for. Launching Jupyter notebook from a shell can help confirming it runs from the correct Python installation.